# Sync problem between Xiaomi and garmin

Tags: garmin

At the moment i own a Xiaomi mi 4c but i going to change it and I noticed that the phone do not sync properly with the garmin 510 I use. In particular while the phone is connected to the garmin via bluetooth do not send the notification about the phone calls and the apps. Anyone has the same problem? Is there a possibility to fix it?

Actually i would like to know if it is a problem about the Xiaomi, in fact the next phone will be another Xiaomi quite for sure!

Comment: And how is this connected to cycling?

Comment: @Erik the OP isn’t getting phone notifications on the Garmin 510 cycle computer when cycling; there might be other SE where it would fit too but other cyclists here might have ideas. I use a 500 so no insight sorry ><

Comment: @Erik By being a question about a cycle computer.

Comment: @erik I would say absolutely yes, given I taking about the connettivity between a smartphone and a cyclecomputer ;)

Comment: Garmin are GPS-devices for me ;)

Comment: absolutely, but we are talking about bicycle gps-device!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Edge 510 does not support the features you are expecting, this functionality was added in later models.

A list of Bluetooth functionality for the Edge510 can be found here: [Link to Garmin site](https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/edge510/EN-US/GUID-6201FE16-EF74-4550-9C6B-4E207539707D.html)

**LiveTrack**

Allows friends and family to follow your races and training activities in real time. You can invite followers using email or social media, allowing them to view your live data on a Garmin Connect tracking page.

**Activity uploads to Garmin Connect**

Automatically sends your activity to Garmin Connect as soon as you finish recording the activity.

**Course and workout downloads from Garmin Connect**

Allows you to search for activities on Garmin Connect using your smartphone and send them to your device.

**Social media interactions**

Allows you to post an update to your favorite social media website when you upload an activity to Garmin Connect.

**Weather updates**

Sends real-time weather conditions and alerts to your device.

Comment: Really? I thought i will support that functionality... well actually is not essential but is something that is useful in some situation. So now I have one more reason to change it to garmin edge 820 :)